# Must I check validation of data if I use woocommerce_wp_text_input()?

Tags: woocommerce

Must do I something as

```
sanitize_text_field( $bar );
```

if I use function

```
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'foo' => $bar ) )
```

for input?

Comment: Yes this is better of course when saving the data and you also should use [**nonce** security](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)…